# Firebase for iOS, GoogleService-Info.plist property "IS_ANALYTICS_ENABLED" set to "NO"

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, firebase-analytics

**Xcode 7.3, iOS 9.3.3**

My GoogleService-Info.plist "IS_ANALYTICS_ENABLED" is set to "NO".  I am integrating Firebase into my iOS app. for the first time.  Will this prevent Firebase from properly analyzing user activity in my app.?

Please advise.

Should I change it to "YES"?

[image]

Comment: Disabling Firebase Analytics will keep it from gathering information on your users. Are you having problems with it?

Comment: I can't tell, the app has not been released.  Should the flag be set to 'no' or 'yes' for analytics to work?

Comment: This seems counter intuitive to me, I downloaded  this file directly from Firebase website, for analytics.  Why it is set to 'no' is beyond me.  Please advise.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Any suggestions Frank?  I think I didn't address the comments to you, so you didn't get notified.

Comment: now that i know its for google analytics, can i manually set as YES in my plist in Xcode. will that lead to my google analytics aso working?

Answer (score 152, accepted):

IS_ANALYTICS_ENABLED refers to Google Analytics for Apps, not Firebase Analytics.  I can see how that is confusing, but it is unrelated to Firebase Analytics.  To read more about the mechanism by which you can disable Firebase Analytics, refer to [this page](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/disable-analytics).

Comment: Thanks Steve.  That explains it.  Very strange for a file I download from the Firebase website for the given app. to have this key, which effects Google Analytics - I figure, if I download a file from Fire base and I am trying to set up Firebase analytics, then it would effect it.  Both belong to Google, I understand.

Comment: Steve, as your profile shows, you are a Product Manager at Google. So, when you understand this is confusing, and as a Product Manager at Google, why is this not cleaned up yet?

Comment: As of 2020 and Firebase 7.0.0, not cleaned up :(

Comment: What do you mean by "Google analytics for apps"?

Comment: This is really confusing. Because Firebase now integrates with Google Analytics for some time. So what is this setting doing?

Comment: It is 2023. It has confused me too :-)

Comment: Just had this happen to me as well... way to go Google!

Comment: Found this confusing too, thought I did something wrong.

Comment: I set this to true in my project, which only just launched (with Firebase). Will this have any negative consequences? For instance, is there any possibility it would fire events twice or anything like that?