# Enabling Debug Mode for Firebase Analytics for Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-analytics

I want to test receiving Firebase Analytics events on my development device. The documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview#ios) says you need to do this by adding a command line argument to Xcode.

> To enable Analytics Debug mode on your development device, specify the
>   following command line argument in Xcode :
>
> `-FIRDebugEnabled`

How are you supposed to do this for Flutter? When you're using it through VS Code or via `flutter run`?

#### Update

I tried following the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43110441/3478500) but to no avail. I think Flutter uses Xcode build, so perhaps it makes sense that adding the params to the run scheme doesn't work with flutter?

I also tried setting `IS_ANALYTICS_ENABLED` to true in `GoogleService-Info.plist`, but also didn't seem to work.

### Update 2

I've gotten the events to now show up in the Debug Events Console on Firebase, but only if I launch the app from Xcode. If I do so from Flutter it still wont send the events (which is what I'm trying to accomplish).

Answer (score 14):

**Open **Xcode****

1. SelctProduct->Scheme > Edit scheme
2. Select Run from the left menu.
3. Select the Arguments tab.
4. In the `Arguments Passed On Launch` section, add `-FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled`.

Answered at [Turning Firebase Analytics on on Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43109486/turning-firebase-analytics-on-on-xcode)
for greater visibility added the link and answer both, Credit should the owner of this answer @checklist.

PS: Currently (oct-23) on [Firebase oficial documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview#ios+) indicate that the command to add is `-FIRDebugEnabled` instead `-FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled`. Test what works for you

Comment: There is also an issue with Flutter and iOS Arguments https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17043 They will only apply if the app is run from Xcode.

Answer (score 3):

I think you might need to use Flutter flavors to pass the FIRDebugEnabled flag when you start the app with `flutter run` instead of through XCode. Please see https://medium.com/@salvatoregiordanoo/flavoring-flutter-392aaa875f36

Answer (score -1):

You can put the Events as ouptut in `NSLOG(..)` which is readable by flutter. If you put it in your swift code basically, you can get the ouput in flutter console.