# Swift 5 Link two different .plist files

Tags: swift, xcode, plist

I have two different **GoogleService-Info** files. One from **Firebase**, other from **Google Analytics**. Is it possible to link both from AppDelegate? Or it possible only with scripts (if only scripts please show me example how to do that). Found only **"if DEV/PROD example on stack"**

Comment: Do you use different accounts for Firebase and Google Analytics? As I remember, if you use one account - you can combine data for two platforms (Firebase and Google Analytics) in one GoogleService-Info.plist file. And about Analitycs - I recommend read [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549074/firebase-for-ios-googleservice-info-plist-property-is-analytics-enabled-set-t)

Comment: @VadimNikolaev its same account, but when you register new app in Analytics, it generate different plist file

Comment: I used one file - there were no issues, I just added data from one file to another

Comment: @VadimNikolaev you just combine both in one file?)

Comment: Yes exactly, just combine

Comment: Will try... spasibo)